# C++ fstream won't open a text file in windows

Tags: c++, visual-studio, fstream

I've written a simple program, and I need to read some numbers from a file.

```
vector<unsigned long> readFile() {
ifstream dat("primes.txt", ios::in);
vector<unsigned long> praSt;
unsigned long i = 0;

while (dat >> i) praSt.push_back(i);

dat.close();

return praSt; }
```

I need to read some primes from a text file and do certain things with them. The problem is that `dat` always ends up being NULL. I tried absolute file paths, relative paths and paths with `\\` as some people recommended but nothing works.

If I run it in a Ubuntu VM it works and reads the file no problem. But I'm used to debugging in Visual Studio (2019). Any and all help would be very appreciated on how to solve this silly problem. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Try an experiment:  In your code, open a file for writing, write some sample text, then close it.  Search your file system for this file.  The containing folder will the default when reading files.

Comment: Or, you could simply query the calling process's current working folder using `GetCurrentDirectory()` instead, that will tell you where files are being accessed from when opened using a relative path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the working directory for the Visual Studio in the project properties, Debugging tab.

The default value is `$(ProjectDir)`.

It's a very dangerous practice to assume that the files you need are in the current working directory - it can change depending on how you start your program. You should either use a "well-known" path (like `APPDATA` on windows) or a path relative to your executable (then you can build that path at run time).